# Issue while installing any Strawberry Perl Module

Tags: windows, perl, module, cpan, strawberry-perl

I'm trying to install a module for Strawbeery Perl on Windows 7 and I'm getting this weird error message:

> E:>cpan Deep::Encode
>   CPAN: CPAN::SQLite loaded ok (v0.203)
>   Creating database file ...
>   Global symbol "$gzerrno" requires explicit package name at C:\strawberry\perl\vendor\lib/CPAN/SQLite/Info.pm line 219.
>   Global symbol "$gzerrno" requires explicit package name at C:\strawberry\perl\vendor\lib/CPAN/SQLite/Info.pm line 223.
>   Global symbol "$gzerrno" requires explicit package name at C:\strawberry\perl\vendor\lib/CPAN/SQLite/Info.pm line 223.
>   Global symbol "$gzerrno" requires explicit package name at C:\strawberry\perl\vendor\lib/CPAN/SQLite/Info.pm line 224.
>   Compilation failed in require at C:\strawberry\perl\vendor\lib/CPAN/SQLite/Index.pm line 11.
>   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\strawberry\perl\vendor\lib/CPAN/SQLite/Index.pm line 11.
>   Compilation failed in require at C:/strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/CPAN/SQLite.pm line 65.
>   system C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe -MCPAN::SQLite::META=setup,update,check -e setup failed: 65280 at C:\strawberry\perl\vendor\lib/CPAN/SQLite/META.pm line 345.

I tried re-installing perl, but I still get this error.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you get from `perl -wE"use strict; use Compress::Zlib; BEGIN { say $Compress::Zlib::VERSION } my $x = $gzerrno; say 'ok'"`?

Comment: `CPAN::SQLite` uses `Compress::Zlib`, whose documentation says *"In "Compress::Zlib" version 2.x, the "gzopen" interface has been completely rewritten"*. Please check the versions of both of these modules: you may need to upgrade `CPAN`

Comment: @ikegami I get this: E:\dev>perl -wE"use strict; use Compress::Zlib; BEGIN { say $Compress::Zlib::VERSION } my $x = $gzerrno; say 'ok'"
Use of uninitialized value $Compress::Zlib::VERSION in say at -e line 1.

Global symbol "$gzerrno" requires explicit package name at -e line 1.
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: Start by reinstalling Compress::Zlib.

Comment: @ikegami, could you clarify whether the OP should truly reinstall the version of Compress::Zlib that they already have, or if they should actually be upgrading Compress::Zlib?

Comment: @Jeffrey Ryan Thalhammer, Well, according to the OP, he has version `undef` of Compress::Zlib. I recommend he doesn't install version `undef` again. That's kinda why he needs to "re"install it.

Comment: I deinstalled Strawberry and installed the recommended version 5.18.2.2 and I still get this error. Shouldn't it work now if it has somthing to do with compatibility between the modules?